# Hoisting issue android Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, hoisting

I am new to Jetpack Compose and am having a problem with the hoisting topic. I have created a very basic app with a button, the app displays the amount of times you have clicked the button. I have tried to hoist the state from one composable to another. The second composable allows you to choose by how much should the increase be by each button click. I know it is possible to achieve everything in one composable but i have decided to hoist the state to the 2nd composable so could practice hoisting. Thanks

```
//Composable that the state has been hoisted to

@Composable
fun chooseYourIncrease(){

    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    
    simpleCounter(countHold = {count + 2})


    
}

@Composable
fun simpleCounter (countHold:(Int)->Unit,
                   modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
        Text("Please press button to increase value", fontSize = 20.sp)

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Button(onClick = { countHold}) {
            Text(text = "Press to increase")

        }
        Spacer(modifier.height(20.dp))

        Text ("The new value is $countHold", fontSize = 20.sp)


    }

}
```

[image]

I get the following output on my screen

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several issues:

- `countHold` lambda does nothing, it needs to actually change the `count` state
- You need to pass `count` state and button logic separately
- Button `onClick` handler doesn't need an `Int`, `count` state will be changed where it is hoisted

```
@Composable
fun ChooseYourIncrease() {
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    SimpleCounter(count = count, countHold = { count++ })    // 1
}

@Composable
fun SimpleCounter(
    count: Int,                                              // 2
    countHold: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
        Text("Please press button to increase value", fontSize = 20.sp)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Button(onClick = countHold) {                        // 3
            Text(text = "Press to increase")
        }
        Spacer(modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text("The new value is $count", fontSize = 20.sp)    // 4
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for formatting this nicely. @M.Khalil: Composables are Capitalised, and arguments should use the arrangement used here.

Comment: Thank you JanItor and Waseem for your help. Its working now. Will keep on practicing until I can truly understand. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Please read about the **State hoisting** [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting). It makes the composable stateless by moving the state to a composable caller. In your case `SimpleCounter()` is the composable you want to make stateless and `ChooseYourIncrease()` is the composable caller. You are in the right direction but need a few modifications in your code:

1. Add a `value: Int` param in `SimpleCounter` composable
2. use the `value` in the text composable to print the count
3. update the value of count in `countHold` callback
4. Always use the `CamelCase` convention to define composable function names.  (**optional** but preferred)

```
@Composable
fun ChooseYourIncrease(){

    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    SimpleCounter(value = count, countHold = { count = count + 2})

}

@Composable
fun SimpleCounter (
    value: Int,
    countHold:() -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){

    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
        Text("Please press button to increase value", fontSize = 20.sp)

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Button(
            onClick = countHold
        ) {
            Text(text = "Press to increase")

        }
        Spacer(modifier.height(20.dp))

        Text ("The new value is $value", fontSize = 20.sp)


    }

}
```

Comment: good explanation.

Comment: Thankyou JanItor and Waseem for your help. Its working now. Will keep on practicing until I can truly understand. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome Khalil. Happy coding.